# Connect Sybase from PHP file

Tags: php, xampp, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm using Sybase Central 16 and I want to access that DB with a PHP file, using XAMPP.

I can run a simple PHP file, but when I wrote some PHP in it, I always have this error

> Fatal error: **Call to undefined function sasql_connect()**

The file only contains:

```
<?php
$conn = sasql_connect( "UID=dba;PWD=sql" );
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connected successfully\n";
    sasql_disconnect( $conn );
} else {
    echo "Connection failed\n";
}
```

I'm using this versions: (running on Win10)

Sybase 16.0

XAMPP 5.6.36 / PHP 5.6

Added this

[image: DLLS to xampp/php/ext folder]

(All programs in x32)

Also have "extension=php-5.6.0_sqlanywhere.dll" on php.ini. I think my problem is with versions nut i cant figure out which ones to use.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you restarted Apache / XAMPP since adding and enabling the extension?

Comment: Yes, after edit php.ini, i stop and start Apache service in Command Center

Comment: Try a simple `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to see what configuration files are being used and what extensions are enabled

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was trying another XAMPP versions, so I have to unnistall and install 5.6 once again. I think i can access that from here: "http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php", but what should i looking for?

Comment: BTW, now I have a different error: "Warning: sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-100] Database server not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 2
Connection failed"

Comment: Sounds like you've got the original problem sorted then as it's trying to make the DB connection. I'd start with the SQLAnywhere documentation

Comment: I think the code I'm using to connect it's supposed to work, since I copied it from a file somewhere in XAMPP files. Also, if Sybase is open and connected to some DB, this should connect to that DB.